# Como fazer eager_load com aninhamento de controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

No método index da controller `Disputes::ConferencesController` listo todas as `conferences` de `disputes`. O endereço URL é `disputes/1/conferences`.

Meu esquema de rotas está dessa forma:

```
resources :disputes do
  scope module: :disputes do
    resources :conferences, shallow: true
  end
end
```

Infelizmente para conseguir as `conferences` preciso fazer 2 queries no banco de dados:

```
Dispute Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "disputes".* FROM "disputes" WHERE "disputes"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Conference Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "conferences".* FROM "conferences" WHERE "conferences"."dispute_id" = $1 ORDER BY "conferences"."scheduled_at" DESC  [["dispute_id", 1]]
```

O método `index` está dessa forma:

```
def set_dispute
  @dispute = Dispute.find params[:dispute_id]
end

def index
  @conferences = @dispute.conferences.order(scheduled_at: :desc)

  render json: @conferences, each_serializer: ConferencesSerializer
end
```

Como contornar isso para somente 1 query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução abaixo resolve essa questão. Basta definir para o método `index` uma query que busca todos os `conferences` através do `dispute_id`, veja abaixo como fica isso:

```
def set_conferences
  @conferences = Conference.where(dispute_id: params[:dispute_id])
                           .order scheduled_at: :desc
end

def index
  render json: @conferences, each_serializer: ConferencesSerializer
end
```

Não esquecer de adicionar as chamadas em `before_action`:

```
before_action :set_dispute, only: :create
before_action :set_conferences, only: :index
```

Espero ajudar algumas pessoas.